# How to print in console while using process

Tags: java, eclipse, file, cmd

I have a problem detecting whether a file exists or not while using running process in meantime. To be more accurate. I found on internet these codes:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class SyncPipe implements Runnable {
public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
  istrm_ = istrm;
  ostrm_ = ostrm;
  }
  public void run() {
   try {
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    for (int length = 0;
     (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
     ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  private final OutputStream ostrm_;
  private final InputStream istrm_;
 }
```

And this:

```
   String[] command = {
    "cmd"
   };
   Process p;
   try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
    new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();

    PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
```

To help me run a Command Prompt and use its commands. So far that's working great. I'm using wget command to connect to a server using username and password to download a file which is after that extracted using 7za command. Those two commands are in cmd. I'm cycling back a month day by day to see if there was a new update to a file. Thing i want to do is when file is founded to stop the for cycle and continue with the program. I've been using `File tmpDir = new File("path"); if(tmpDir.exists()) break;` . But after running several testings and finally seeing why it doesn't work i found out that program first do these testings and then start executing program with cmd involved. I tried that putting syso in random places within code and all of them where first executed and then Command prompt started its work. With any help i will be grateful. If there is still something unclear, say.

Code sample:

```
String[] command = {
"cmd"
};
Process p;
try {
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);   
new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();   
PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());

for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
stdin.println("wget -r --output-document=file.zip --http-user=user --http-password=pass http://example.com");
stdin.println("7za e file.zip");
File tmpDir = new File(file.zip);
System.out.println(tmpDir.getAbsolutePath());
if(tmpDir.exists())
    break;
}
```

Reduced code from program. This `absolutePath()` is printed onto console 30 times before both `stdin.println()`

Comment: Putting some sample code should be easier to underderstand than all this long text

Comment: @jeanr I hope its better now

Comment: Thanks, can you just clearly point where is the problem, what is the expected behavior and what is the behavior you currently have

Comment: @jeanr Behaviour i currently have: Program first checks 30 times whether a file exists and prints on console filepath, and after that it starts a cmd and executs wget command. I don't know what should be expected behaviour, i want to know how to download a file using wget and right after that tmpDir.exists() trigger and breaks the for cycle.

Comment: Can you provide a working main function please, there is a lot of error in the code you just add

Comment: @jeanr [link](https://pastebin.com/0FYb6xmS) You said there is a lot of error in code i've just added. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I was speaking about the code sample in your post, we can't test it as it ('}' missing at the end of the for loop, stdin.println("7za e file.zip) --> a " missing)